# How to find eigenvalues $\lambda>0$ so that matrix A is positive and definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

We are given matrix A:
\begin{pmatrix} 
  s    & -1 & -1\\ 
  -1 & s & -1\\
-1&-1&s\\ 
\end{pmatrix}
I need to find for which s do A has all eigenvalue $\lambda>0$(positive definite).

The main problem is that i can try with different values but i will never found all of them.
Is there a trick to do this?

Comment: Have you tried finding the eigenvalues in terms of $s$? (it looks like an ugly cubic, but...)

Comment: you have to sove $det(A-\lambda I)=0$, this is a polynomial and you will get something like $(\lambda-\alpha_1)(a\lambda^2+b\lambda+c)$, then you have to check the determinant and play with $s$ to get all $\lambda>0$.

Comment: @theage, no it doesn't so ugly, it results $(s-\lambda)^3-2(s-\lambda)-1$

Comment: ...glad to hear it, I guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The eigenvalues $\lambda$ of $A$ are given by:
$$\det{\left(A-\lambda I\right)}=0\Longleftrightarrow\begin{vmatrix}s-\lambda&-1&-1\\-1&s-\lambda&-1\\-1&-1&s-\lambda\end{vmatrix}=0$$
Expanding the determinant and simplifying a bit, you get the following characteristic equation:
$$(\lambda-s-1)^2(\lambda-s+2)=0$$
Therefore, the eigenvalues are $\lambda=s+1(\text{twice}),s-2$. Thus, if you want $A$ to be positive definite:
$$\lambda>0\Longrightarrow s-2>0\Longleftrightarrow s>2$$

Comment: @Xenomorph $\ldots=s^3-3s^2\lambda+3s\lambda^2-\lambda^3-3s+3\lambda-2=(-\lambda +s-2)(\lambda^2-2s\lambda-2\lambda+s^2+2s+1)=(-\lambda +s-2)(\lambda^2-2\lambda(s+1)+(s+1)^2)=(-\lambda +s-2)(\lambda -s-1)^2$

Comment: @Xenomorph It's easier if you can guess a root first.

Comment: @Xenomorph Yes... so what?

Answer (score 2):

[Sylvester's criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester's_criterion) tells you that the conditions are
\begin{align}
&\det\begin{pmatrix} s \end{pmatrix}>0\\[12px]
&\det\begin{pmatrix} s & -1 \\ -1 & s\end{pmatrix}>0\\[12px]
&\det\begin{pmatrix} 
  s    & -1 & -1\\
  -1 & s & -1\\
-1&-1&s\\ 
\end{pmatrix}>0
\end{align}

This means $s>0$, $s^2-1>0$, $s^3-3s-2=0$. The third condition reads $(s+1)^2(s-2)>0$, so the final solution is $s>2$.

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to compute the characteristic polynomial.

the reason is that this matrix is a rank one peroration of a scalar matrix $(s+1)I.$  the eigenvalues of $uu^\top$ where $u^\top = (1,1,1)$ are $u^\top u = 3, 0, 0.$ therefore the eigenvalues of $$A = (s+1)I - uu^\top $$ are $s-2, s, s.$ for $A$ to be positive definite, you need $s > 2.$